# Moving columns under other columns in R

Tags: r, dataset

I have to work with an existing dataset and want to move the content of some columns (in this example the content of columns F to J) under the content of columns A to E so that the length of the dataset doubles (as it is displayed in columns O to S). Doing this manually is not reasonable for my large dataset nor is it elegant. Do you know a **R Code** that lets me choose which columns content to move **under** existing content in other columns without altering any values? Solutions I found focussed on merging values of different columns, e.g., by adding them up, but I want the single values to be unaltered, just moved.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as 
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
because it is about how to use R without a reproducible 
example.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I'm voting to close this question as 
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
because it is about how to use R without a reproducible 
example.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen When a brand new user asks their first question, we usually try to be more welcoming and encouraging than a close vote.

Comment: Descolith, it's much easier to help you if you share a small copy/pasteable example in valid R syntax rather than a screenshot of a spreadsheet. If your data is in R already, you can create a copy/pasteable version of the first 5 rows with `dput(your_data[1:5, ])`. The output may look strange, but it can be copy/pasted in to R to replicate your data, include all class and structure information.

Comment: That said, at a glance, you may be able to do something like `rbind(your_data[, 1:5], your_data[, 6:10])`. If that doesn't work or you need more help, please do work on sharing a small reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

I recreated your data into an Excel spreadsheet named "ExcelPivot.xlsx". Below is the code I used to get the desired solution, as you depicted in your picture:

```
##Libraries.##
library(readxl)
library(writexl)
library(tidyverse)

##Inputs - reads in grouped data.##
##You must specify the ranges.
dataFirstHalf<-read_xlsx("ExcelPivot.xlsx", range="A1:E13")
dataSecondHalf<-read_xlsx("ExcelPivot.xlsx", range="F1:J13")


##Binds together the grouped data, to be pasted in later.##
TransformedData<-rbind(dataFirstHalf, dataSecondHalf)

##Binds together the two halves of the dataset.##
AllData<-cbind(dataFirstHalf, dataSecondHalf)


##Adds in blank columnns based on the question.##
AllData<-AllData%>% add_column(blank=NA_character_, .name_repair = "minimal")
AllData<-AllData%>% add_column(blank2=NA_character_, .name_repair = "minimal")
AllData<-AllData%>% add_column(blank3=NA_character_, .name_repair = "minimal")
AllData<-AllData%>% add_column(blank4=NA_character_, .name_repair = "minimal")

##Makes the AllData DF the same size as the transformed data.##
AllData[nrow(AllData):nrow(TransformedData),]<-NA

##Binds together the transformed data with the original data set.##
AllData<-cbind(AllData, TransformedData)

##Removes NAs to be blanks.##
AllData <- as.data.frame(sapply(AllData, as.character))
AllData[is.na(AllData)] <- ""

##Writes to an Excel file.##
write_xlsx(AllData, "AllData.xlsx")
```

One major drawback is that you will need to remove the "blank" column headers. But it does closely arrive at the solution you wanted.